# Matlab Regexp - Lookbehind With Ignored Characters in Expression

Tags: regex, matlab, regex-lookarounds

I have a list of files with in the format below mixed with other file types, defined in the file name. I want to extract the index number if it is proceeded by specific text. The catch is that the proceeding text contains variable characters ('ignored_123456'). 'fileType' is a specific string identifying the file type I am looking for. The variable text to be ignored is likely a fixed length if that helps.

Example:

```
testString = 'fileType-ignored_123456_deck-0001_index-0005.ext';
```

I want to filter file names that include a specific 'fileType' and 'deck-0001' and then extract the index number '0005'

I attempted to use a 'wildcard' within the expression:

```
filePattern = '(?<=fileType.*deck-0001_index-)\d+';
fileIndex = str2double(regexp(testString,filePattern,'match','once'));
```

I also tried:

```
filePattern = 'fileType[a-zA-Z0-9-_](?<=deck-0001_index-)\d+';
```

and:

```
filePattern = '(?<=fileType[a-zA-Z0-9-_]deck-0001_index-)\d+';
```

Any suggestions? Ideally I would like to keep this as a single line expression to pass into an existing function, but can make an update if there is no easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a capturing group in the regex instead and use the `regexp` with [`tokens`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#btrlyqq-1) option set:

```matlab
testString = 'fileType-ignored_123456_deck-0001_index-0005.ext';
tokens = regexp(testString, 'fileType.*deck-0001_index-(\d+)', 'tokens','once');
tokens{1,1}
```

Output:

```
0005
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out 'tokens'. I could get this to work but would require some updates in other files. Do you know if there is a way to use 'match' so that the returned array is not nested cells when calling the regexp on a cell array of strings? Tokens appears to be more useful when there are multiple matches found within one string.

Comment: @mtourtelot In Octave, I get `tokens = regexp(testString, 'fileType.*deck-0001_index-\K\d+', 'match','once');` to work, because PCRE is installed. If neither than, nor `tokens = regexp(testString, '(?<=fileType.*deck-0001_index-)\d+', 'match','once');` work for you, there is no other way.